# loading data from external stage - only truncate + load when theres new file

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm loading data from a named external stage (S3) by using COPY INTO, and this S3 bucket keep all old files.

Here's what I want:
When a new file comes in, truncate the table and load the new file only, if there's no new file coming in, just keep the old data without truncation.

I understand that I can put option like FORCE = False to avoid loading old files again, but how do I only truncate the table when there's new file coming in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would likely do this a bit differently, since there isn't a way to truncate/delete records in the target table from the `COPY` command.  This will be a multi-step process, but can be automated via Snowflake:

1. Create a transient table.  For sake of description, I'll just call this `STG_TABLE`.  You will also maintain your existing target table called `TABLE`.
2. Modify your COPY command to load to `STG_TABLE`.
3. Create a STREAM called `STR_STG_TABLE` over `STG_TABLE`.
4. Create a TASK called `TSK_TABLE` with the following statement

This statement will execute only if your `COPY` command actually loaded any new data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK TSG_TABLE
WAREHOUSE = warehouse_name  
WHEN SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('STR_STG_TABLE') 
AS  
INSERT OVERWRITE INTO TABLE (fields)
SELECT fields FROM STR_STG_TABLE;
```

The other benefit of using this method is that your transient table will have the full history of your files, which can be nice for debugging issues.